# Voice Biometrics for Android

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition, voice, biometrics

i am planning to build a voice authentication system for android devices. Simply meaning instead of the login screen where you have to type your password or draw the pattern, you only only need to say one word such as "Login" and the phone authenticates you and automatically unlocks the phone.

I was initially planning to implement it on windows but i am afraid that windows might not support voice bio metrics.

So my question is will android support voice bio metrics for unlocking a phone? 
Are there any voice bio metrics libraries for android ?

I did a google search but couldn't really find what i wanted. I have also found out some voice biometrics apps such as nuance but their authentication is implemented for a different purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: There is https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito, but it's a bit initial state. You can try to improve it.

Comment: i have the same problem^^...found a lib (http://voicevault.com/), but couldn't try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Android does support voice authentication by its own. You can have this feature by using an external library. Several companies offer online voice biometrics, but only a few offers offline.

If you are looking for offline voice authentication I would suggest the following companies:

- [Neurotechnology](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verispeak.html)
- [Agnitio](http://www.agnitio-corp.com/products/commercial/speaker-verification)

They both support multiple platforms.