# Biometric using Voice - Android

Tags: java, android, algorithm, voice-recognition, biometrics

I want to create an android app that can recognize user's voice and authenticate the user, Can anyone help me to find any library code or algorithm?

thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-voice-recognition-tutorial.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voice Biometrics for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757102/voice-biometrics-for-android)

Answer (score 2):

Look at **CsBence** answer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757102/voice-biometrics-for-android/26682824#26682824)

> Android does support voice authentication by its own. You can have
>   this feature by using an external library. Several companies offer
>   online voice biometrics, but only a few offers offline.
>
> If you are looking for offline voice authentication look at companies:
>
> - [Neurotechnology](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verispeak.html)
> - [Agnitio](http://www.agnitio-corp.com/products/commercial/speaker-verification)
>
> They both support multiple platforms.